# How can I parse this JSON for my Discord Bot?

Tags: python, json, discord

My Python program receives JSON data, and I need to get bits of information out of it. How can I parse the data and use the result? I think I need to use json.loads for this task, but I can't understand how to do it.

My Code is this.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="stats", description="Stats")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def stats(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    embed = discord.Embed(title=f"Stats",description="Stats", color=0x9824cc)
    headers={"api" : '---'}
    stats = json.loads(requests.get('http://---/stats', headers=headers).text)
    #print(stats)
    print(stats['message'])
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

And this is my .json file i want to read.

```
{"type":{"overall":{"message":1111111111,}}}
```

Now i want to read just the 1111111111.

discord.app_commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command 'stats' raised an exception: KeyError: 'message'

Answer (score 0):

You will need to replace `stats['message']` by `stats['type']['overall']['message']`. If this was the only problem, this should work.